# How can i fix this error on weka?

Tags: csv, weka, feature-selection

I want to insert large size of csv file into Weka for feature selection.
the csv file size is about 2.3GB and it contains 41 line with 2,000,002 columns.

first line contains
    (sample_id) (1~2,000,000) (class)

and from second line
    ID float float float ... Class(Y/N)

However When I try to insert this file to weka, popup the error message:

> weka.core.coverters.CSVLoader failed to load 'test.csv'. Reason: Wrong
>   number of values. Read 1000002, expected 100001,  read Token[EOL] line
>   2 Problem encountered on line: 2

I don't know why this error comes out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is just trying to tell you that some line in the input iis not consisting of 2000002 (specified) columns. Just check with specified line in error or lines surrounding it for whether they are consisting of right number of columns. It should solve your problem.

As number of columns (features) are too large just count number of commas (if your input is comma separated) with ctrl+f in line. With this you can find no of columns in that line.

Hope that it has helped!

Answer (score 0):

Check your datasets for missing values. I once encountered that error and I found out that there are missing value in my dataset.